# How to send file within input tag using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-java

How do I send a file link to load on the page using selenium?

```
<input type="file" id="filArquivo" class="infraInputFile" name="filArquivo" size="50" onchange="objUpload.executar();" tabindex="1000">
```

Does not work:

```
WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="filArquivo"]'))).send_keys("Doc.pdf")
```

Does not work:

```
WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'filArquivo'))).send_keys("Doc.pdf")
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.infraInputFile[name='filArquivo']"))).send_keys("/path/to/Doc.pdf")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(navegador, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='infraInputFile' and @name='filArquivo']"))).send_keys("/path/to/Doc.pdf")
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use full path to file (os.path.abspath)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).